# Does anyone know more about Eomer? Like who he married, and whether he had children?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

I was always interested in Rohan-related things, and therefore Eomer. I wanted to know if anywhere in the original book (that I've never had), there was mention of what happened to him.

Answer (score 21):

From *Lord of the Rings*; Appendix A; Part II, *The House of Eorl*; section *Third Line*:

> Éomer became a great king, and being young when he succeeded Theoden he reigned for sixty-five years, longer than all their kings before him save Aldor the Old. In the War of the Ring he made the friendship of King Elessar [Aragorn], and of Imrahil of Dol Amroth; and he rode often to Gondor. In the last year of the Third Age he wedded Lothiriel, daughter of Imrahil. Their son Elfwine the Fair ruled after him.
>
> In Éomer's day in the Mark men had peace who wished for it, and the people increased both in the dales and the plains, and their horses multiplied. In Gondor the King Elessar now ruled, and in Arnor also. In all the lands of those realms of old he was king, save in Rohan only; for he renewed to Éomer the gift of Cirion, and Éomer took again the Oath of Eorl. Often he fulfilled it. For though Sauron had passed, the hatreds and evils that he bred had not died, and the King of the West had many enemies to subdue before the White Tree could grow in peace. And wherever King Elessar went with war King Éomer went with him; and beyond the Sea of Rhun and on the far fields of the South the thunder of the cavalry of the Mark was heard, and the White Horse upon Green flew in many winds until Éomer grew old.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add on to Rand's answer, Éomer's fate is also mentioned in another of Tolkien's writings.

> The Rohirrim were generally shorter, for in their far-off ancestry they had been mingled with men of broader and heavier build. Éomer was said to have been tall, of like height with Aragorn; but he with other descendants of King Thengel were taller than the norm of Rohan, deriving this characteristic (together in some cases with darker hair) from Morwen, Thengel's wife, a lady of Gondor of high Númenórean descent.
>
> She was known as Morwen of Lossarnach, for she dwelt there; but she did not belong to the people of that land. Her father had re­moved thither, for love of its flowering vales, from Belfalas; he was a descendant of a former prince of that fief, and thus a kinsman of Prince Imrahil. His kinship with Éomer of Rohan, though distant, was recognized by Imrahil, and great friendship grew between them. **Éomer wedded Imrahil's daughter [Lothíriel], and their son, Elfwine the Fair, had a striking likeness to his mother's father.**
> <sub>Notes associated with "The Disaster of the Gladden Fields" (c.1969), published in *Unfinished Tales*</sub>